# "getIntent()" - How it works

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Learning how to make android apps and I did this tut.  Summary of the tut is here:

http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2012/10/android-simple-user-interface-activity.html

I'm trying to figure out how intents work. In the tut you create an Intent called intent, and in DisplayMessageActivity.java it creates an Intent called intent by calling "getIntent()".

Does the "getIntent()" function (or method (I'm most familiar with C)) just return the most recently created intent? Can there only be one intent at a time?

Thnks in advance for any responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Activities are started by either the `startActivity(Intent)` or the `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` methods.  The intent tells the Activity everything it needs to know to display the correct information at launch.  `getIntent()`, when called in an Activity, gives you a reference to the Intent which was used to launch this Activity.

Comment: Do you always need an Intent to start an activity? or will startActivity accept other types of parameters?

Comment: You always need an Intent.  Intents can contain all sorts of information, like which Activity is asking to start this one, Extras which are primitive variables and Parcelable objects used to tell the new Activity what data it has to work with and you can also specify Actions for what you want the new Activity to do (i.e. browse something, pick a value, etc).  In any case, an Activity can only be started with an Intent so getIntent() should never return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

`getIntent()` method gets the `intent` that called this activity.there can be more than one intent but you have only one intent visible at one time (since only one activity is visible at one time)

Answer (score 0):

> There are two primary forms of intents you will use.
>
> Explicit Intents have specified a component (via
>   setComponent(ComponentName) or setClass(Context, Class)), which
>   provides the exact class to be run. Often these will not include any
>   other information, simply being a way for an application to launch
>   various internal activities it has as the user interacts with the
>   application. Implicit Intents have not specified a component; instead,
>   they must include enough information for the system to determine which
>   of the available components is best to run for that intent.

An Intent is a data class which holds information for an Activity that is about to be started. An Activity is a manager or controller for the view which is currently displayed on the screen.

> Activities in the system are managed as an activity stack. When a new
>   activity is started, it is placed on the top of the stack and becomes
>   the running activity -- the previous activity always remains below it
>   in the stack, and will not come to the foreground again until the new
>   activity exits.

[image]

Comment: Intents are not Activities

Comment: To quick written and i made mistake in words.

Answer (score 0):

An [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is typically created through an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Assuming you are in your first activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyFancyActivity.class, Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
startActivity(intent);
```

This launches a new `MyFancyActivity` instance. From `MyFancyActivity`, you can retrieve the intent which lead to that instance creation. That is, the `getIntent()` method:

```
// this is the intent created in your first activity
Intent i = getIntent();
```